# Mongo Query: GraphLookup or Aggregate

Tags: mongodb

Looking for some direction on how to construct a mongo query for a graph network visualization.

I have a data model that looks like this:

```
stories[
{
  story: "story 1",
  theme_ids: [1,2,3],
  author_ids: [a,b,c]
},
{
  story: "story 2",
  theme_ids: [4],
  author_ids: [a]
}
...
]
```

I would like the result of the query to grab all of the pairs of themes and authors like so:

```
[
{from: 1, to: a},
{from: 1, to: b},
{from: 1, to: c},
{from: 2, to: a},
{from: 2, to: b},
{from: 2, to: c},
{from: 3, to: a},
{from: 3, to: b},
{from: 3, to: c},
{from: 4, to: a}
]
```

Thank you!  MongoDB v3.4

Comment: Would like to remove duplicates from the result set as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use double [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get all pairs:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            from: "$theme_ids",
            to: "$author_ids"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$from"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$to"
    }
])
```

If you need to remove the duplicates you can add [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with `$addToSet`:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        uniquePairs: { $addToSet: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}
```